# Match data of columns with tolerance

Tags: oracle

ok, i have a requirement to match address data in two tables in oracle database with a tolerance of 2. Meaning when matching the values 'abc de fghij' and 'abd el fghij' should return true. and these 2 different characters can be anywhere and can be at different places and can be apart too.
I have googled and googled but could not find a function or logic for anything like this. Can someone please guide me to where to look at for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE('abc de fghij', 'abd el fghij')` for your problem. This calculates the `Levenshtein Distance` between the two strings.

This also allows for characters to be added or deleted in addition to your request but should be a good starting point.

So the final query could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(<COLUMN>, :PARAMETER) <= 2
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what i was looking for. really appreciate your knowledge on oracle. thank you

Comment: To be honest it was more the knowledge of the right keywords to search for but glad i could help you none the less...

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
with t(a, b) as ( 
  select 'abc de fghij', 'abd el fghij' from dual union all
  select '1234', '456784' from dual )
select a, b, 
       length(trim(translate(a, b, ' '))) ab,
       length(trim(translate(b, a, ' '))) ba
  from t
```

Returns:

```
A            B                    AB         BA
------------ ------------ ---------- ----------
abc de fghij abd el fghij          1          1
1234         456784                3          4
```

which means that in row 1 there is one character in A which is absent in B and one in B which is absent in A.

If this logic is OK then write your query as:

```
select a, b
  from t
  where length(trim(translate(a, b, ' '))) + length(trim(translate(b, a, ' '))) <= 2
```